# TimerTask exception

Tags: java, mysql, timertask

I can't open my mysql connection at run method inside timertask class. It throws an exception. When I trying to run this class in my mainclass with a timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(backgroundexecution, 0, 5000); method, It is not working. Anyone have any idea about how I can solve this problem?

```
@Override
public void run() {//here is my run method
        backgroundtask obj = new backgroundtask();
        try{
        Statement statement = obj.openConnection(); //it throws an exception at this line
        String mysqlcommand = "Select *from abc";
        ResultSet sonuc = statement.executeQuery(mysqlcommand);

        while(sonuc.next()){
            if(search.contentEquals(sonuc.getString("ssa"))){
            System.out.println(sonuc.getString(2));
        }
        }
        statement.close();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception? Post full stacktrace.

Comment: If you changed your catch statement to `System.out.println(ex.toString());` it would help in diagnosing what the exception is.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I just found my fault. I forgot to import library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line before you attempt to carry out a db query (it loads the database drivers class);

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If your using a different db driver the string may be different. Also ensure jdbc is in your classpath.